# Mounting a share in fstab (Debian 11) fails with BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Tags: debian, fstab, cifs

I can run `sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,user=root //SERVER_NAME/SHARE /mnt/FOLDER` without issue. However, I cannot run `mount -a` or `mount /mnt/folder` when I have this line in fstab:

```
//SERVER_NAME/SHARE /mnt/FOLDER cifs guest,user=root 0 0
```

This seems to resemble this error:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/1896699

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error log (accessed via `sudo dmesg`) was very misleading, which only emitted:

```
[ 1532.759381] CIFS: VFS:  BAD_NETWORK_NAME: \\SERVER_NAME\SHARE
[ 1532.762864] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Since the Samba share was set up for guest access with no write or modify permissions, what the line in fstab needed was `noperm`, like so:

```
//SERVER_NAME/SHARE /mnt/FOLDER cifs guest,user=root,noperm 0 0
```